# How to get reference for TELEPHONY_SERVICE inside fragment class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have Fragment which is called inside Fragment Activity want to get To Get Unique Device id inside fragment I am using

```
/* To Get Unique Device id */
    TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    szImeiId = TelephonyMgr.getDeviceId(); // Requires READ_PHONE_STATE
```

but gives me error at TELEPHONY_SERVICE how to get reference for this 
please help me to make it work
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE` constant like this..

```
TelephonyManager manager=(TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TelephonyManager TelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

Comment: getSystemService() not a method in fragment